# IE 11 Browser issue

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, ie11-developer-tools

This is sample code.

html
div id="test"
div form elements like uname and pwd 1st div end

2nd div end
For the child div there is no nameor id.

Var

```
x=document.getElementById("test");
</html>
```

It is returning object but i was unable to print values..i was unable to find length of object. In IE11.

Please help on this.

Comment: _“i was unable to find length of object”_ – you have a reference to an HTML element here, and those don’t have a “length.”

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this works for your scenario:

```
x=document.getElementById("test");

var a = x.length;

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. it was giving undefined in ie11.